# I want to select data from a combo box and pull it through to my button using an IF statement in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, combobox

I created a combo box and button in Excel using VBA. I want my button to run an IF statement and based on the selection in the combo box to go to a different worksheet. But my current code is giving me a "object required" error when debugging.

Please help?

Here's my current code:

```
Sub Button9_Click()
    If DropDown13.Value = "Access Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AccMA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Audit Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AudMA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Asset Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AssMA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Benefits Realisation" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BenMA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Business Continuity Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BCMA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Business Process Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BPMA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Capacity Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CAPA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Catalogue Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Change Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CNGA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Communications Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMA").Activate

    ElseIf DropDown13.Value = "Compliance Management" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COPA").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your combobox?  On a userform?  On a worksheet?

Comment: Hi Brain,On a worksheet

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a combobox named "DropDown13" Is the posted code in the sheet module for the worksheet which has the combobox?  If you use `Option Explicit` it will warn you about this type of problem at compile-time, instead of waiting for the run-time error

Answer (score 0):

You have a known 1:1 relationship between dropdown13 values and the sheets you wish to activate.  Therefore you can totally avoid a long and complicated if/elseif by using a Scripting.DIctionary.

```
Option Explicit

Dim mySheets As Scripting.Dictionary
   

Sub Button9_click()

Dim myValue As String

    myValue = dropdown13.Value
    
    If mySheets Is Nothing Then SetupMySheets
    
    If mySheets.Exists(myValue) Then
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheets.Item(myValue)).Activate
        
    Else
    
        'raise an error because the requested sheet doesn't exist
        
    End If
    
End Sub


Public Sub SetupMySheets()

    Set mySheets = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    With mySheets
    
        .Add "Access Management", "AccMA"
        .Add "Audit Management", "AudMA"
        .Add "Asset Management", "AssMA"
        .Add "Benefits Realisation", "BenMA"
        .Add "Business Continuity Management", "BCMA"
        .Add "Business Process Management", "BPMA"
        .Add "Capacity Management", "CAPA"
        .Add "Catalogue Management", "CATA"
        .Add "Change Management", "CNGA"
        .Add "Communications Management", "COMA"
        .Add "Compliance Management", "COPA"
        
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Use late bound declaration to avoid reference errors.  `Dim mySheets As Object` and
 `Set mySheets = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

Comment: Late binding is poor advice if the op is new to Scripting.Dictionaries. Admittedly the OP appears to be a bit slow on the uptake because they don't realise that they have to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  However, I am of the opinion that advising people to use late binding is bad bad bad because is removes the option for intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

I think your core problem is you don't have any control named "DropDown13" on the worksheet.

*Once you resolve that*, then maybe consider using `Select Case` instead of the more-verbose `If ElseIf` approach.

```vb
Sub Button9_Click()
    
    Select Case Me.DropDown13.Value
        Case "Access Management": sht = "AccMA"
        Case "Audit Management": sht = "AudMA"
        Case "Asset Management": sht = "AssMA"
        'etc etc
        Case Else: sht = ""
    End Select
    
    If Len(sht) > 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Activate

End Sub
```